# Unable to use ISCHANGED in HTML email template

Tags: email-template

I am using expression `{! IF( ISCHANGED( customObject__c.Amount__c), 'changed', 'notchanged') }`

But on `Send test and Verfiy Merge fields`, it is not showing any values.

However, `ISBLANK` and `ISPICKVAL` function works fine in `html Email template` condition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use ISCHANGED in an email template. As the [documentation](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&type=5) says:

> This function is available only in:
>
> - Assignment rules
> - Validation rules
> - Field updates
> - Workflow rules if the evaluation criteria is set to Evaluate the rule when a record is: created, and every time it’s edited .
> - Formula criteria for executing actions in the Process Builder.

Whatever you're trying to do, you'll need to come up with an alternative method of doing this, perhaps as a trigger update.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide the link for the documentation?

Comment: @devforce Added a link to help file.